# How are voltage dividers used in circuits?

Tags: resistors, circuit-design, voltage-divider

I am a newbie and wanted to understand in simple terms how a voltage divider maybe used to for instance, power 2 different LEDs of different voltages if they were within a circuit.

The main issue that concerns me is where the drop occurs. Before the resistor or after the resistor. I know from diagrams tutorial videos that the multimeter is usually connected with one terminal before and one after the resistor but that doesn't help with the placement of components according to my inferior understanding of this matter.

Please kindly provide guidance so I may clarify my problems further.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You wouldn't use a voltage divider for powering an LED, you'd just use a single series resistor to limit the current.

Comment: You say "the resistor", but traditionally a voltage divider consists of at least two resistances. Also, as Andy aka hinted, LEDs are current-driven devices. You should focus on their current, not their "voltage". Try not to think of LEDs needing different "voltages" at this point.

Comment: Thank you for your replies guy. Can you please give me a practical example of how a voltage divider could be used in a circuit, as I seem to have completely misunderstood the point and purpose of a voltage divider?

Answer (score 2):

Voltage dividers are usually used to reduce the voltage to provide a fraction of the supply voltage to a device - a transistor's base, for example. For LEDs we control the current with a simple series resistor. While it does reduce the voltage we don't refer to it as a voltage divider due to the non-linear ratio caused by the diode's characteristics.

> The main issue that concerns me is where the drop occurs. Before the resistor or after the resistor.

Voltage is dropped across both the resistor and the LED. This can be confirmed with a simple experiment.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqlLrq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) Resistor then LED. (b) LED then resistor.*

I've chosen the resistor as 1k to provide about 10 mA which will light most small LEDs brightly.

- VM1 will measure about 10 V.
- VM2 will measure about 2 V due to the forward voltage, V<sub>F</sub>, of the LED.

You can swap the LED and resistor as in Figure 1b and the end result will be the same. Note that neither component is "aware" of the other's position.

[image]

*Figure 2. LED IV curves showing the non-linear relationship between current and voltage in various colours of LED. Note that the V<sub>F</sub> is dependent on the doping of the semiconductor and the doping determines the colour. [Image source](http://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/iv-curves/).*

Answer (score 1):

The voltage drop is shared between the resistors the amount each resistor drops depends on the ratio between the resistors.

They are best used as a voltage reference for a high impedance input. That way the input doesn't affect the voltage level itself.

You can replace one of the resistors with a zener diode in which case the voltage drop across the zener stays stable when the load draws more or less current.

You can also replace one of the resistors with a component whose resistance changes depending on the environment (influence by light, temperature, etc.) and use the change in output voltage to switch a transistor.

Comment: Thank you for your answers guys. Can you provide me with any additional examples of how and where a voltage divider could be utilised?